# call custom phtml with Ajax or Knockout in magento admin order detail page

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, jquery, knockoutjs

anyone know how we can call custom phtml in order detail page admin side.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should override template Magento_Sales::order/view/history.phtml file by using below code.

view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml

```
<referenceBlock name="order_history">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::order/view/history.phtml</argument>
        </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

Then, copy main Magento_Sales::order/view/history.phtml to your Vendor_Module and modify it as per your requirement

Comment: This way I am already working on but without that did you have any idea????

Comment: I do not think so if any other Magento way to do the same but if you really want to do that, you can add that block to anywhere in order total section then prepend or append it with comment box using jquery or js.

Comment: In the same way, we are doing. 

Did u know after over right template how we can load custom phtml through knockout js??

Comment: If you add a block to anywhere you do not need to override history template. I was talking about to add a custom block in sales_order_view with a custom template and then using jQuery js you can move the element. But if you do it via knockout js I think this is the suitable tutorial https://webkul.com/blog/use-knockout-js-custom-template-magento2/

Comment: Ok i will review and update according.

Comment: anyone have an idea how we can call phtml with ajax and knockout js . all  phtml files must be load with knockout js..

Comment: awesome..It works